# Counting connected graphs with largest eigenvalue greater than 2 and the Kostant game

Tags: graph-theory

I work on a variation of the Kostant game on graphs where I introduce a real parameter different form -1 at the "mutation" node. This game is known to end after a finite number of firing iff the graph is a Smith graph. These graphs are also known as the famous and ubiquitous ADE graphs (2 infinite families of graphs, the $A_n$ et $D_n$  graphs and 3 exceptional graphs $E_6, E_7, E_8$. The J.H Smith theorem asserts that they are the only connected graphs with largest eigenvalue strictly less than 2.

If we accept that maximum eigenvalue is 2 we get the extended Smith graphs. Still a finite number.

My question is:

Whats happen if I accept max eigenvalue in the range $[2;2 + \epsilon]$?

For $\epsilon=0$, we get the family of extened Smith graphs. For $\epsilon > 0$, do I still get something similar with well identified infinite family of graphs like the $A_n$ et $D_n$ and some exceptional finte graphs or is it more "chaotique" ?

[image]

For example if you take $D_n$ and you add an extra edge like hereabove you get the following spectra

λ_max≈2.05288 > λ_2≈1.20864 > λ_6≈0.569973 > ...

In that case the Kostant game is not finite but my variation is for the real parameter  ≈ -0.974241 instead of -1 as in the Kostant game.

Thanks for any help